# How to resolve "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have tried to add my custom layout into my main layout. I have followed the following link https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2013/02/10/android-add-views-into-view-dynamically/#.Xa6la5MzbVo . But I am getting the error like this. [image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should add the `view` instead of `textView` into `parentView`

Comment: YOu shouldn't add the View, that *depends if you're using a `<merge` tag or not*. What you should do, is show the parentLayout XML **and** the `text_layout` XML. So we can recommend an informed approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding same textview every time in your parent layout.
You have to add different view.
It can be done as-

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("Row"+i);
parentLayout.addView(tv1)
```

without findviewbyid

Answer (score 0):

Change `parentLayout.addView(textView)` to `parentLayout.addView(view)`

because the `textView` already has a parent ,i.e, the `view which is inflated` !.

```
parentLayout.addView(view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before add the new view you have to clear previous view

**if(viewName.childCount > 0) viewName.removeAllViews()**

Comment: What if i don't want to clear the view and want to add next view below??